# Volcanology book to make an app for first courses students

Tags: geology, volcanology

I want to make an app for first courses geology students that include the types of volcanoes and eruptions.

Can you recommend me a book (in English, French or Spanish) that could help me make the students learning process more profitable?

It should contain designs to do my own work with [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

Comment: There could be copyright issues if you simply replicate someone else's graphics.

Answer (score 3):

Try David Rothery's "Volcanoes, Earthquakes and Tsunamis" in the Teach Yourself series. Really well written and authoritative.

Comment: Welcome Mark and thanks for the answer. I am the poster of the question. I want to know before buying it: does the book cover all the kinds of volcanoes and eruptions? Has it graphics about types of volcanoes?